# Retrieve DisplayName Attribute from Class

Tags: c#

So I have this code in a test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetClassDisplayName()
{
    string displayName = DisplayNameHelper.GetDisplayName<ApplicantInfoJob>();

    Assert.AreEqual(displayName, "APPLICANT_INFO_JOB");

}
```

and this code in a helper class

```
 public static string GetDisplayName<T>()
 {
     var displayName = (DisplayNameAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

     if (displayName != null)
         return displayName.DisplayName;
     return "";
 }
```

but the displayName is always null then using typeof(T) but works fine if I change it to

```
var displayName = (DisplayNameAttribute)typeof(ApplicantInfoJob).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();`
```

I'm not sure why the type is not working. Anyone have any ideas?

Class Signature:

```
[DisplayName("APPLICANT_INFO_JOB")]
public class ApplicantInfoJob : RequiredDatesBaseEntity
{
}
```

Comment: I've checked your code, it's working well. Please check this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JH8Xrw). Maybe your problem comes from other point.

Comment: I moved the function into the test and it did work properly. For some reason having it in the main project in a helper class was causing issues. Do I need to moc that helper class? could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe moc of your helper class will help.

Comment: Funny thing is I just moved it back the helper class and reverted the call to access that method and now it's working fine.

Comment: Stuff like that drives me nuts.

Comment: That's great news!!!!!